# pandas read file avoiding unwanted separators

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns, separator

I am reading a csv file that looks like this:

"column, column, column, column,"column, column

if I read using sep=',' I only get three columns.

Any Idea of how to parse this type of file?

Comment: The sep function in read_csv allows you to pass in multiple delimiters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `quotechar` in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) from pandas,

```py
df = pd.read_csv(PATH, quotechar="'")
print(df.columns.tolist())

['"column', ' column', ' column.1', ' column.2', '"column.1', ' column.3']
```

Comment: Thanks!, it works. However I don't undestand how it works. It makes sense for me that the quotechar would be ' " ' as the double quote is the characther I'm trying to escape.

Comment: I first thought like you. But `pandas` reads the double quote as a single quote. For instance, output is `['column, column, column, column,column', ' column']` for expression `pd.read_csv(PATH).columns`. As you can see, does not contains double quote.

Comment: Hi again @DavidLópez. If my answer was helpful, don't forget [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it. :)